# Random crashes occur in my iphone project, see two call stacks, all in web core, all crash after UIWebView deallocate

Tags: iphone, random, crash

Random crashes occur in my iphone project, see two call stacks, all in web core, all crash after UIWebView deallocate.

See crash 1, seems web core can't close it completely,  is it blocked by other running threads?

See crash 2, why it is still dealing with some issues even if UIWebView has been released?

Any idea or discussion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Crash 2 has higher reproducible rate than crash 1, scan WebCore source code, it seems be manifest cache has been deleted (who did it?) when try to access it.

[image: web core crash 1]

[image: web core crash 2]

Comment: I had some trouble with WebViews a while back, and it was because it was still loading some web content when it was released. Maybe this could be the culprit?

Comment: Maybe it is the problem, but why it is still loading data after UIWebView instance has been released? And invoke stopLoading, According to Apple's doc, it will tear down all connections.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're setting some object (probably your view controller) as the delegate of your webView, either via Interface Builder, or via code that looks something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.webView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

This code has a serious bug that's not immediately obvious if you don't know what to look for.  Can you spot it?

When the controller gets dealloc'd it releases the webView, but this doesn't necessarily mean the web view no longer exists.  It may still be retained by some code down inside its internal implementation, and it may still be loading content.

When it finishes loading, the web view will call a method like `webViewDidFinishLoad:` on its delegate.  The problem is, your view controller was the delegate, and your view controller no longer exists.  The section of memory where your view controller used to live has been reclaimed by the operating system, and is no longer accessible to your application process.  The web view doesn't know this though.  It still has a reference to that memory address in its delegate property.  So it tries to call a delegate method on that object, and whoops... EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Crashes like this appear to be random since they depend on what your app is doing in the background at the time.  This makes them tricky to diagnose.  Fortunately they're easy to solve.  Simply set the object's delegate to nil before you release it your dealloc statement, like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.webView.delegate = nil;
    [self.webView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

By setting the web view's delegate to nil before you release it, you guarantee that the web view won't try to call delegate methods on your object after it's been deallocated.

If you're using ARC, your class may not have a dealloc method.  That's normally fine, but in a case like this you should go ahead and add one.  You don't want to call `release` if you're using ARC, but you should still add a dealloc method and set the delegate property to nil.

To avoid similar crashes in the future, apply this best practice any time you set your object as the delegate of another object.

Comment: Thanks you guy's smart reply. I have set UIWebView's delegate to nil in dealloc method, it is still crash, more with attachment call stack 2. My confusing is that why UIWebView has been released, it still tries to load other resources?

Comment: We use HTML 5 manifest for offline feature, my debugging shows that the crash occurs during reloading manifest files.

Answer (score 0):

Before releasing the webview, try to reset the delegate an stop loading.

```
[webView stopLoading];
webView.delegate = nil;
[webView release];
webView = nil;
```

Comment: perhaps you can post more code, on how you setup the webview, when you push / remove the viewcontroller etc.

Comment: We encapsulate UIWebView dues to we need to use PhoneGap to interact with both HTML and native actions.

Comment: One question, you stopLoading then release webView immedicately, is it safe? are you sure all URL connections will be teared down? Thanks.